Type Hinting: An attribute won't change value after creating an instance of the class
I have an abstract class Task that describes the volume_id attribute. The int value is the ID of the volume that the specific task is for. In the case that the task is not for a specific volume (a "general" task), then it's value is just None. See example code below:
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Union


class Task(ABC):
    volume_id: Union[int, None]

    @abstractmethod
    def run(self) -> None:
        return


class GeneralTask(Task):
    volume_id = None

    def run(self) -> None:
        # Do something without using volume_id
        return


class SpecificTask(Task):
    volume_id = None
    
    def __init__(self, volume_id: int) -> None:
        self.volume_id = volume_id
        return
    
    def run(self) -> None:
        # Do something that uses volume_id
        int(self.volume_id)
        return

The problem is that my type checker/static analyser complains in the SpecificTask.run function that the value of self.volume_id could potentially be None. This is only true in the scenario where an instance of the class is created, the value of the attribute is manually changed to None, and then the run() function is run. This scenario doesn't come up in my code base and should be prohibited anyway.
How can I make clear and enforce that the type of volume_id will not change after running __init__ (it can be an int or None, we set it to an int and it won't change back)? I tried changing the typehint to Final[int] in the __init__ function, but then the static analyser complains that I'm overriding the type hint from the abstract class...

Can you simply change volume_id = None to volume_id: int in SpecificTask?

Why have a volume id in Task at all, if it's specific to SpecificTask?

@mkrieger1 then my static analyser complains that I'm overriding the variables type hint.

@chepner because in the real code it's not that simple. There are about 15 tasks, about 1/3 is general and 2/3 is for a specific volume. There is a lot of code that handles any of these class instances regardless of which specific implementation it is. The fact that the value is None for half of them is fine, but the attribute should be there.

The code that doesn't care about volume_id gets defined in Task; the code that does gets defined in SpecificTask.

Yes but there is code outside of these classes that handles instances of the classes and that code expects there to be a volume_id attribute. Anyway, I already have my answer and it works.

Remove all your volume_id = from all classes. These are class variables (as in @staticmethod variables) not class instance variables. So:
SpecificTask.run()

Will make self.volume_id reference SpecificTask.volume_id which is None.
If you do not want volume_id to be None, do not set it. Do not do volume_id = None then.
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Union


class Task(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def run(self) -> None:
        return


class GeneralTask(Task):
    def run(self) -> None:
        # Do something without using volume_id
        return


class SpecificTask(Task):
    def __init__(self, volume_id: int) -> None:
        self.volume_id = volume_id
    
    def run(self) -> None:
        # Do something that uses volume_id
        int(self.volume_id)

Childs can't override class variables, as they are variables of a specific class type. If you want to have volume_id, create a property, which then child instances can override.
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod, abstractproperty
from typing import Optional, override


class Task(ABC):
    @abstractproperty
    def volume_id(self) -> Optional[int]:
        raise NotImplementedError()
        
    @abstractmethod
    def run(self) -> None:
        return


class GeneralTask(Task):
    @override
    @property
    def volume_id(self) -> None:
        return None
        
    @override
    def run(self) -> None:
        # Do something without using volume_id
        return None


class SpecificTask(Task):
    def __init__(self, volume_id: int) -> None:
        self._volume_id = volume_id
        
    @override
    @property
    def volume_id(self) -> int:
        return self._volume_id
    
    @override
    def run(self) -> None:
        # Do something that uses volume_id
        int(self.volume_id)

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

The typing.override decorator is only available in python 3.12 or higher (but is not essential for the code to work). The abc.abstractproperty decorator is marked as deprecated in 3.8, but can be replaced by @property + @abstractmethod. With these changes it works perfectly in python 3.8. Thanks!

You can use typing-extension for override in older python versions. It's just cosmetics.
